# Cannot create custom field JIra Rest Api

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

Hi I was wondering if anyone could help me with the following.
I am trying to create an issue with a custom field (check boxes) which is an array.

My field in the browser(when I hit http://xxxxxxxx//rest/api/latest/issue/issueId) comes up like this :

```
"customfield_10703":["val1","val2","val3"],
```

but when I try to Post it in create Issue I get :

```
{
"errorMessages": [],
"errors": {
"customfield_10703": "Operation value must be a string"
}
}
```

I should mention that I have managed to successfully create an issue when I encode it like this

```
"customfield_10703":"{\"name\": \"Harware setup\"}",
```

But the problem now is that I cannot create more than one value.

ps. I have already checked administration page and my field is on default screen. 
Thanks.

Comment: ["val1","val2","val3"] is an array, not a key/value pair. It works if you send it as {"name":"whatever"} because Jira receives it as a key/value pair.

Comment: Try "customfield_10703":(["val1","val2","val3"]).join() instead, this way your custom field will get sent a string instead of an array.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look a the "createmeta" for your project. You can retrieve it by making a GET request to `<your_jira_server>/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta?expand=projects.issuetypes.fields&projectIds=<project_id>`

That should give you more detailed information about the expected format for the data your field. With checkboxes, you'll generally find something like:

```
"customfield_10600": {
    "required": false,
    "schema": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": "option",
        "custom": "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:multicheckboxes",
        "customId": 10600
    },
    "name": "My Checkbox",
    "key": "customfield_10600",
    "hasDefaultValue": false,
    "operations": [
        "add",
        "set",
        "remove"
    ],
    "allowedValues": [
        {
            "self": "<your_jira_server>/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10400",
            "value": "apples",
            "id": "10400"
        },
        {
            "self": "<your_jira_server>/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10401",
            "value": "bananas",
            "id": "10401"
        },
        {
            "self": "<your_jira_server>/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10402",
            "value": "grapes",
            "id": "10402"
        },
        {
            "self": "<your_jira_server>/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10403",
            "value": "kiwi",
            "id": "10403"
        },
        {
            "self": "<your_jira_server>/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10404",
            "value": "limes",
            "id": "10404"
        },
        {
            "self": "<your_jira_server>/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10405",
            "value": "oranges",
            "id": "10405"
        },
        {
            "self": "<your_jira_server>/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10406",
            "value": "pears",
            "id": "10406"
        }
    ]
}
```

When you're sending it back to JIRA, it expects an array of `option` types. For options, you should be able to use either a `{"name": value}` or `{"id": id}` JSON object (I've only ever used the ID approach). You should use the value or id from the list of allowed values.

If you want to set more than one, you'll need to send an array of those option objects.